# Creating camera lens material

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, glass, reflection

I'm creating a camera lens, and I have problems with creating a glass material. As you know, this kind of glass has colored reflections caused by special anti reflective coating (actually, glasses have this effect too). What nodes setup I need to achieve this result?[image]

Comment: Which result exactly? Cycles is limited at calculating caustics...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a lens shader be made in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158629/can-a-lens-shader-be-made-in-cycles)

Comment: No, I mean adding colours to reflection, as on image (added to post)

Comment: Hello :). For adding colored reflections, this thread could be useful https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35815/78972